# Ajax not working using jquery url post method

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to make a stepy-form for my project. What I want to do is I want to submit all my data step by step in stepy-form so I used an AJAX request for this purpose, but When I am trying to save it it's not working. So I used `noConflict` Method to avoid jQuery conflicts but I still have the same problem. I am using adminEX template And Not getting any error message. So can anyone help me?

```
<script src="ajax/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $.noConflict();
    Jquery(document).ready(function(){
        $('#stepy_form').click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'ajax/insert_all.php',
                data: {
                    txtVehicleNo: txtVehicleNo,
                    SltType: SltType,
                    txtPANNumber: txtPANNumber,
                    txtManufacture: txtManufacture,
                    txtModel: txtModel,
                    txtEngineNumber: txtEngineNumber,
                    txtChassisNumber: txtChassisNumber,
                    txtOwnerName: txtOwnerName,
                    txtUnlaidenWt: txtUnlaidenWt,
                    txtGVW: txtGVW
                    //  qid: 'form1'
                },
                //alert('hello');
                //async: true,
                //cache: false,
                success: function(result) {
                    alert('SUCCESS');
                    //$('#target').html(result);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

And this one is the URL ,insert_all.php

```
$qid = $_POST['qid'];
echo $qid;
```

Comment: Why does this 'not work'? Can you give any details about error messages, expected behaviour and actual behaviour.

Comment: Please provide error message you are getting.

Comment: and why did you commented out the `//  qid: 'form1'`?

Comment: I created a test code for this and its working fine

Comment: The basic HTML

<input type = "text" id = "txt1" name = "txt1">

<input type = "button" name = "btninput" id = "btninput">

<div id = "result1">bbgusdbugbsduvbgusgbusdb</div>

<script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#btninput").click(function(){
  var txt1 =$('#txt1').val();
  var qid ="form1";
  alert(txt1);
  //alert(cat);
  $.ajax({url:"backend.php?name="+txt1,
  success:function(result){
  $("#result1").html(result);
  }});
  });
  });
</script>


And here is the Backend.php

<?php
 $a = $_REQUEST['name'];
 echo $a;
?>

Comment: Not getting any error message

Comment: @user3193751 Please EDIT your question and include that information (and any other)

Comment: try change click  - live // jQuery 1.3+
or delegate // jQuery 1.4.3+  or on // jQuery 1.7+

Answer (score 0):

You are not using 'no conflict' with jquery and accessing it using `$`. Change $ with jQuery like this

```
$.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#stepy_form').click(function(){
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'ajax/insert_all.php',
            data: {
                txtVehicleNo: txtVehicleNo,
                SltType: SltType,
                txtPANNumber: txtPANNumber,
                txtManufacture: txtManufacture,
                txtModel: txtModel,
                txtEngineNumber: txtEngineNumber,
                txtChassisNumber: txtChassisNumber,
                txtOwnerName: txtOwnerName,
                txtUnlaidenWt: txtUnlaidenWt,
                txtGVW: txtGVW
            },
            success: function(result) {
                alert('SUCCESS');
                //$('#target').html(result);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I suggest you to use the above code once and share the error again

Comment: I am using notepad++ so how to trace the error with it

Comment: not to trace but look into the browser. if you have firefox than install firebug as addon and it will help you to trace your js errors

Comment: OKay I am trying ,will tell you ...bunch of Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: got 2 errors 

TypeError: jQuery.validator is undefined
http://localhost/transport/admin/js/jquery.stepy.js
Line 59


TypeError: 'stepUp' called on an object that does not implement interface HTMLInputElement.
http://localhost/transport/admin/ajax/jquery.min.js
Line 4